# SQL Server CE application with user permissions

Tags: c#, winforms, security, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to develop an application that allows the managing of users via WinForms and a SQL Server CE database. I've established a way for users to login via a login set in a table database with a username and password columns.

Now, I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about limit access to specific features of the application. My goal is to sort the application into modules (Customers, Employees, Billing, etc.) and the give the user read write permissions for the entire module. Later on I might try to implement security on a per-form basis.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create Roles Table on your SQL CE.

So your UserTable might have a `RoleID FK` added in each user.

Let say you have Admin and a User Role.

In each of your form, add Security handler Methods / Class that checks the Role of the user who access your application.

Create `public string Role;` and `puclic string UserName` in each of your form you can pass its values to rest of the form.

Example on Customer Form Load you can add

```
if(Role=="Admin")
{
    //visible all controls stuff
}
else
{
    //User
    //set controls to read only stuff
}
```

On your Login Form Logon/Ok Click event

You can do

```
//your stuff on getting the role of the user 
//validation stuff
string role =  // get user role;  
if (role!=null)
{
    //if you have MDI Parent
    var mdi = new MDIParent
    {
        UserName = txtUserName.Text,
        Role = role,
    };
    mdi.Show();    
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    //Error user not valid!!
}
```

Best Regards